# Calculate diffrence between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, difference

I have a DB with two date column (Y-m-d):

```
Date_from    Date_to     
17/01/01     17/01/05       
17/02/03     NaN           
17/05/01     17/05/05       
...
```

Date_from and Date_to are pandas column.

I built a function that if:
- in Date_to there NaN returns me "corrence";
- in Dta_to there is no Nan makes the difference between the two columns

Both results are saved in a third column. Like this:

```
Data_from    Date_to     Difference
17/01/01     17/01/05       4
17/02/03     NaN           corrence    
17/05/01     17/05/05       4
...
```

The function is this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def diff(data,d1, d2):
    if pd.isnull(data.iloc[[1],[12]]):
         data['difference'] = 366
    else:
         data[d1] = pd.to_datetime(data[d1])
         data[d2] = pd.to_datetime(data[d2])
         data['difference'] = data[d2] - data[d1]
    return data

d1 = ["Date_from"]
d2 = ["Date_to"]
df = replace_NaN(df,d1,d2)
```

The error that get out is this:

```
TypeError: replace_NaN() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I don't understand why

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a function to do this. Instead,

1. Convert the columns to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`
2. Subtract `Date_from` from `Date_to`
3. Extract the days component of the `timedelta` columns using `dt.days`
4. Call `fillna` on the result

```
i = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_to, format='%y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
j = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_from, format='%y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')

df['Difference'] = i.sub(j).dt.days.fillna('corrence')
```

```
df

  Date_from   Date_to Difference
0  17/01/01  17/01/05          4
1  17/02/03       NaN   corrence
2  17/05/01  17/05/05          4
```

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi yes.